# Building a c++ application with gradle on host linux aarch64

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, gradle, arm64

My host is a linux aarch64 machine on Android Galaxy Tab S4 with Termux installed as my development environment.
Installed in Termux is NDK v22, Clang 12.0.2, Gradle 7.1.1, android-sdk (30.0.3) and kotlin 1.5.21.

I init'ed a new c++ application project with gradle and the default template project-files and directories were initialized.

When I try to build now the project, I got following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugCpp'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerVersion' of task ':app:compileDebugCpp'
   > No tool chain is available to build C++ for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64':
       - Tool chain 'visualCpp' (Visual Studio):
           - Visual Studio is not available on this operating system.
       - Tool chain 'gcc' (GNU GCC):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64'.
       - Tool chain 'clang' (Clang):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

My use-cases will be, to build c++ libraries, later using kotlin/native and integrating as last task everything into an apk with the help of gradle/kotlin/ndk etc.

What does this error mean?
Is there really no support for linux aarch64 hosts or do I need to change some configuration settings in the build.gradle file?

I searched the gradle documents, internet and kotlin/native manual but cannot found a solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is Clang found if you try to call it directly without gradle?
Please make sure that you can compile anything with Clang from command line.

Then you may need to fine tune your native tool chain for Gradle as described in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#native_binaries:tool_chain

Comment: Yes, clang is working correctly from the cli. Everything is fine from a usual 'Hello World', jni-project and android ndk

Comment: When I tried the examples in this link, I got an error: > Invalid NativePlatform: linux_aarch64.

Comment: For linux_aarch64 see also https://discuss.gradle.org/t/tool-chain-gcc-gnu-gcc-dont-know-how-to-build-for-platform-linux-aarch64/19232/2. Even if is already older hopefully helps you

Comment: thank you for the link. I tried this example  with no success. log: > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > No tool chain has support to build C++ for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64':
       - Tool chain 'clang' (Clang):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64'.
   > No tool chain has support to build C++ for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64':
       - Tool chain 'clang' (Clang):
           - Don't know how to build for host operating system 'Linux' architecture 'aarch64'.